# c++ boost on mac compile error

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I've tried with/without -m64 option, it is not working. How should I fix this?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in main-6996c8.o
      boost::system::error_code::error_code() in main-6996c8.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in main-6996c8.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main-6996c8.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in main-6996c8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: yr gonna have to show the compile and link commands

Comment: I installed boost with brew. The command is g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp

Comment: what does the `include` statement look like in the source code for `main-6996c8.o`?

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using Xcode or using command line?
Second, the problem probably is that the include dir and lib dir are not set up correctly. 
Third, you can go to /usr/local/include to check if you have boost headers and go to /usr/local/lib to check if you have boost libs.

Comment: certainly not an include problem, its a link / lib issue